# Zoom in animation - c4framework

Tags: ios, c4

I am playing with the deferent animations using the alpha C4 framework.

I am trying to  shape grow from the midel of the canvas till it covers it completely....Is there  any animation that can create that zoom effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, you can change and animate a C4Shape like this:

```
shape.animationDuration = 1.0f; //1 second animation duration
[shape rect:(-1,-1,769,1025)];
```

Note, the above is for a rectangle that will be 1px larger than the screen of an iPad on all sides. To make an ellipse you'd have to figure out the size of the frame that will encompass an ellipse that covers the whole screen.

Comment: Haha, vertical integration at its best:  You wrote the framework, and then get the rep for questions about it.

Comment: Hopefully I'm not the only one for long! We're really trying to push the development.

Comment: To be honest, the prospect of working on something like C4 is quite interesting to me.  Send an email to devteam.codafi(at)gmail.com if you need any help.